# how to change picture using drop down list?

Tags: php, javascript, drop-down-menu

I want to use a drop down list, every time i click the content in it, different pictures will show up. But i don't want to use the property 'value', because i want to use the values for other use.

Example:

```
<select name='test'>
<option value='1'>1</option>
<option value='2'>2</option>
<option value='3'>3</option>
<option value='4'>4</option>
</select>
```

How do i accomplish that?

Thanks.

**Edit:**

with pointy's suggestion, it works.

```
<select name="dpt" onChange="picture.src=this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-whichPicture');" >
<option value="1839" data-whichPicture='./imgs/t1.jpg' >01</option>
<option value="1661" data-whichPicture='./imgs/t2.png' >02</option>
</select>
</select>
<img src='' id='picture' />
```

**Edit:**

There is a problem, that is if i refresh the page, the default the picture will display but the selection in the drop down list will stay. How to fix that?

Comment: You need to use the bracket notation to refer to properties with a special character in JavaScript:
`this.options[this.selectedIndex]["data-whichPicture"]`
See: http://www.dev-archive.net/articles/js-dot-notation/

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the "class" of each option to hold some indicator of what image to show. If you're writing in HTML5 like all of the Beautiful People nowadays, you can use a "data" attribute:

```
<option value='1' data-whichPicture='http://whatever.com/picture_017.jpg'>1</option>
```

You can in fact stick any attribute you want on your tags, but it'll leave the page in a non-valid state.  The HTML5 attributes aren't validated yet (I don't think; the HTML5 validator I last tried was pretty dodgy), but the W3C promises that they will be someday.

*edit* — also - your question mentions that you want to change pictures when somebody "clicks" on the `<select>`.  You can in fact get "click" events from each `<option>`, but you should probably also watch for "change" events. Users can tab into your `<select>` and use up- and down-arrow keys to change selection. You won't get the "change" event until the user tabs out of the `<select>` or clicks somewhere else.  (It might be possible to get "keypress" events; I haven't tried that but I just might ...)

*edit* — To get the attributes (if you use the "data-" trick), you have to use the "getAttribute" method on the elements:

```
var whichPicture = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-whichPicture');
```

Comment: Thanks pointy, it's applicable in the applications right now? I've tried to use it, but it doesn't display the picture.

Comment: Uhh ... I'm not sure what you mean. Maybe if you posted more of your code it would help.

Comment: OK I added to my answer. You have to use "getAttribute" to fetch those things.

Comment: There is a problem, that is if i refresh the page, the default the picture will display but the selection in the drop down list will stay. How to fix that?

Comment: You could reinitialize the page in the handler for the "load" event on the window.  `window.onload=function() { ... }`

Comment: I can use onload to assure the picture i have chosen stays the same?

Comment: You can use a handler for "load" to reset the page to whatever initial state you think it should be in. If there's a "default" picture and you want the dropdown list to show the corresponding value, then your "load" handler would force the `<select>` to show that one by setting "selectedIndex" to the right value.

Comment: i don't understand it very well. Normally there is an default image, when i click one item in the drop down list and submit, it will show the default image, but the item is still what i have chosen.

Comment: I suggest that you ask a new question about this - maybe somebody will understand better than I do!

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a map between the option values and the images

```
{ 1: "imgA.png", 2: "imgB.png" }
```

and then use a function to load the correct image based on this mapping.

Another approach might be to augment the value with the image name, like this,

```
<select name='test'>
<option value='1;imgA.png'>1</option>
<option value='2;imgB.png'>2</option>
</select>
```

And then use string functions to parse out the number value or the image name as required.

Comment: A map or an associative array really is the best and foolproof way of doing this, imo.

Answer (score 0):

You can put multiple values in the 'value' field by separating them with delimiters.
You would have to split the value and select the one you want to use when displaying your image

```
<option value="1,dogs.jpg">1</option>
<option value="2,hogs.jpg">2</option>
<option value="3,cats.jpg">3</option>
<option value="4,dogs.jpg">4</option>
```

Comment: That's certainly possible, but it seems icky to have to burden the server-side code with throwing away the extra stuff, or to have to deal with that upon form submission. Of course, if there's no server-side action involved, then it doesn't matter.

Comment: How to use the second parameter in the 'value' property?

Comment: Depends on where you are using the Value...in Javascript or C#.

In JavaScript, you have to split the value into an array of substrings, then select the second element in the array that's created:
http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-string-split.php

In C#, same idea..use the split method on strings:
http://dotnetperls.com/string-split
then select the second element in the array.